# Android AlarmManager Won't Start Service

Tags: java, android, service, alarmmanager

I have two implementations of AlarmManager which are supposed to start two services - LMW and BWM - for some reason BWM starts each time and LMW does not. I've looked the source code over many times and I'm really not sure why this could be happening.

P.S.

adb shell dumpsys alarm shows a reference to BWM but no reference to LWM

Any input is greatly appreciated!

ALARMMANAGER SOURCE:

```
public class Rules extends Activity {
    private String password;
    private PendingIntent mPendingIntent;
    String TIMELIMIT = "10";

    TextView textSsid, textSpeed, textRssi, Time;

    private static final int NOTIFY_ME_ID = 1337;
    private int count = 0;
    private NotificationManager notifyMgr = null;
    public Handler mHandler = new Handler();
    public long mStartRX = 0;
    public long mStartTX = 0;
    public long txBytes;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.rules);

        String NDEF_PREF = "prefs";
        SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences(NDEF_PREF,
                Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        String name = prefs.getString("name", "");
        String code = prefs.getString("corename", "");
        String time = prefs.getString("time", "");
        String ssid = prefs.getString("restricted", "");
        Time = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Time);
        Time.setText(time);
        textSsid = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Ssid);
        textSpeed = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Speed);
        textRssi = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Rssi);
        Time = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Time);
        Long.toString(mStartTX);
        Long.toString(mStartRX);
        Long.toString(txBytes);
        mStartRX = TrafficStats.getTotalRxBytes();
        mStartTX = TrafficStats.getTotalTxBytes();
        if (mStartRX == TrafficStats.UNSUPPORTED
                || mStartTX == TrafficStats.UNSUPPORTED) {
            AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
            alert.setTitle("Uh Oh!");
            alert.setMessage("Your device does not support traffic stat monitoring.");
            alert.show();
        } else {
            mHandler.postDelayed(mRunnable, 1000);
        }

    }

    private final Runnable mRunnable = new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            TextView RX = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.RX);
            TextView TX = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.TX);

            long rxBytes = TrafficStats.getTotalRxBytes() - mStartRX;
            RX.setText(Long.toString(rxBytes));
            long txBytes = TrafficStats.getTotalTxBytes() - mStartTX;
            TX.setText(Long.toString(txBytes));
            mHandler.postDelayed(mRunnable, 1000);

            final Chronometer myChronometer = (Chronometer) findViewById(R.id.chronometer);
            myChronometer.start();

            DisplayWifiState();
            this.registerReceiver(this.myWifiReceiver, new IntentFilter(
                    ConnectivityManager.CONNECTIVITY_ACTION));

        }

        private void registerReceiver(BroadcastReceiver myWifiReceiver2,
                IntentFilter intentFilter) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        private BroadcastReceiver myWifiReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {

            @Override
            public void onReceive(Context arg0, Intent arg1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                NetworkInfo networkInfo = (NetworkInfo) arg1
                        .getParcelableExtra(ConnectivityManager.EXTRA_NETWORK_INFO);
                if (networkInfo.getType() == ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI) {
                    DisplayWifiState();
                }
            }
        };

        public Date getTimeFromTimeString(String time) {
            String[] splitStrings = time.split(":");

            Date timeDate = new Date();
            timeDate.setHours(Integer.parseInt(splitStrings[0]));
            timeDate.setMinutes(Integer.parseInt(splitStrings[1]));
            return timeDate;
        }

        // Long.parseLong(time)

        public void DisplayWifiState() {

            ConnectivityManager myConnManager = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
            NetworkInfo myNetworkInfo = myConnManager
                    .getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI);
            WifiManager myWifiManager = (WifiManager) getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
            WifiInfo myWifiInfo = myWifiManager.getConnectionInfo();

            if (myNetworkInfo.isConnected()) {

                textSsid.setText(myWifiInfo.getSSID());

                textSpeed.setText(String.valueOf(myWifiInfo.getLinkSpeed())
                        + " " + WifiInfo.LINK_SPEED_UNITS);
                textRssi.setText(String.valueOf(myWifiInfo.getRssi()));
            } else {
                textSsid.setText("---");

                textSpeed.setText("---");
                textRssi.setText("---");
            }
            ;

            // Start service using AlarmManager

            Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
            cal.add(Calendar.SECOND, 10);
            Intent intent = new Intent(Rules.this, LMW.class);
            PendingIntent pintent = PendingIntent.getService(Rules.this, 0,
                    intent, 0);
            AlarmManager alarm = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
            alarm.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, cal.getTimeInMillis(),
                    7 * 1000, pintent);

            String NDEF_PREF = "prefs";
            SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences(NDEF_PREF,
                    Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
            String name = prefs.getString("name", "");
            String code = prefs.getString("corename", "");
            String time = prefs.getString("time", "");
            String ssid = prefs.getString("restricted", "");

            // Start 2nd service using AlarmManager

            // Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
            // cal.add(Calendar.SECOND, 10);
            // Intent intent2 = new Intent(Rules.this, KillTimer.class);
            // PendingIntent pintent2 = PendingIntent.getActivity(Rules.this, 0,
            // intent2,
            // 0);
            // AlarmManager alarm2 = (AlarmManager)
            // getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
            // alarm2.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,
            // cal.getTimeInMillis(),
            // time != null ? 1000 : 0, pintent2);

            // Date futureDate = new Date(new Date().getTime() + 86400000);

            // futureDate.setHours(8);
            // futureDate.setMinutes(0);
            // futureDate.setSeconds(0);

            // Start 3rd service using AlarmManager
            Intent intent3 = new Intent(Rules.this, BWM.class);
            PendingIntent pintent3 = PendingIntent.getActivity(Rules.this, 0,
                    intent3, 0);
            AlarmManager alarm3 = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
            alarm3.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, cal.getTimeInMillis(),
                    7 * 1000, pintent3);

            // click listener for the button to start service
            Button btnStart = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
            btnStart.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    startService(new Intent(getBaseContext(), LMW.class));
                    startService(new Intent(getBaseContext(), BWM.class));
                    Intent startMain = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
                    startMain.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
                    startMain.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                    startActivity(startMain);

                }

            });

            // click listener for the button to stop service
            Button btnStop = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
            btnStop.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    stopService(new Intent(getBaseContext(), LMW.class));
                    Intent startMain = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
                    startMain.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
                    startMain.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                    startActivity(startMain);

                }
            });

        }
    };
}
```

LMW SOURCE:

```
public class LMW extends Service {
    String Watchdog = "Watchdog";
    String Dirty1 = "playboy";
    String Dirty2 = "penthouse";
    String Dirty3 = "pornhub";
    String Dirty4 = "thepiratebay";
    String Dirty5 = "vimeo";
    String Dirty6 = "wired";
    String Dirty7 = "limewire";
    String Dirty8 = "whitehouse";
    String Dirty9 = "hackaday";
    String Dirty10 = "slashdot";
    Long mStartRX = TrafficStats.getTotalRxBytes();
    Long mStartTX = TrafficStats.getTotalTxBytes();

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Watchdog Running!",
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        Parse.initialize(this, "7gjqmUcoqu1IZPJSSxXLdE4L8efAugCXA7snLSH6",
                "5NckF83MUBumQ8L8zL7Akc4p07beMRnmvgCfhZdH");

        ParseUser.enableAutomaticUser();
        ParseACL defaultACL = new ParseACL();

        // If you would like all objects to be private by default, remove this
        // line.
        defaultACL.setPublicReadAccess(true);

        ParseACL.setDefaultACL(defaultACL, true);

        Long.toString(mStartTX);
        Long.toString(mStartRX);
        ParseObject testObject = new ParseObject("TestObject");
        testObject.put("DataO", String.valueOf(mStartTX));
        testObject.put("DataI", String.valueOf(mStartRX));

        testObject.saveInBackground();
        String[] projection = new String[] { Browser.BookmarkColumns.TITLE,
                Browser.BookmarkColumns.URL };
        Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(
                android.provider.Browser.BOOKMARKS_URI, projection, null, null,
                null);
        String urls = "";
        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            String url1 = null;
            String url2 = null;
            do {
                String url = cursor.getString(cursor
                        .getColumnIndex(Browser.BookmarkColumns.URL));
                // Log.i(Watchdog, url);
                if (url.toLowerCase().contains(Dirty1)
                        || url.toLowerCase().contains(Dirty2)
                        || url.toLowerCase().contains(Dirty3)
                        || url.toLowerCase().contains(Dirty4)
                        || url.toLowerCase().contains(Dirty5)
                        || url.toLowerCase().contains(Dirty6)
                        || url.toLowerCase().contains(Dirty7)
                        || url.toLowerCase().contains(Dirty8)
                        || url.toLowerCase().contains(Dirty9)
                        || url.toLowerCase().contains(Dirty10)) {
                    Intent intent2 = new Intent(LMW.this, Warning.class);
                    intent2.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                    startActivity(intent2);
                    break;
                }
            } while (cursor.moveToNext());

        }

        return START_STICKY;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {

        super.onDestroy();
        Toast.makeText(this, "Service Stopped", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();

    }
}
```

Comment: What API level is this for?  You're using the onStartCommand, but not all API levels use that. You may want to try changing your onStartCommand to something like "startup" then making onStartCommand and onStart both call startup.  In otherwords, it may be as simple as the wrong method being used.

Comment: API16 - Thanks! BTW - Can you show an example?

Comment: Use `adb shell dumpsys alarm` to see the status of your alarm. Confirm that your service is registered in the manifest. Check LogCat for relevant warnings. And, no, `onStartCommand()` is unlikely to be your problem, as that has been around for about four years.

Comment: That's true.  I assumed everything else was all set.  Have you tested to see if your service will start by hand?  ie, it too is registered as a service?  Run through this tutorial http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidServices/article.html and verify you have everything set.

Comment: That Vogella tutorial is actually how I built my first Service Class : ) I simply copied the 1st one I made to make the 2nd and 3rd and the first and second one are working. BTW - how can I start it by hand? Would that be done by using my manifest?

Comment: @CommonsWare - I ran dumpsys alarm - what am I looking for in here? I've read through it and I see one reference to it: +1s877ms 164 wakes 164 alarms: cmp={com.app.demo/com.app.demo.BWM>

Comment: That means that your alarm was scheduled to go off 1.877 milliseconds from the time you ran that command. Hence, your alarm exists and is trying to start your service. Consider using `Log.d()` rather than a `Toast` for determining if your service is running or not, or use a breakpoint.

Comment: @CommonsWare - Now BWM is running as it should be - but LMW isn't and both should be running at the same time - any idea why this might be? (I've updated my source and my notes above)